# Is there way to implement value based pagination without exposing a score the end user

Tags: postgresql, express, security

I have a system where product offers are presented to the user in a paginated list. This list is ordered by a hidden score, that I don't want the user to know, to avoid people reverse engineering the scoring algorithm.

In order to efficiently page the list, I would like to use this hidden score. So with every page the user would receive all page entries as well as the hidden score of the last entry as a nextPage parameter.  When this score is sent to the server, it will fetch all posts with a score higher and then return the first 30 entries it finds.

Now a competent attacker would probably be able to use this pretty easily to figure out the score of any post and then reverse engineer the algorithm behind it.

So is there a way to easily hide this hidden score? I was thinking of encrypting it, but depending on the encryption algorithm, this may add significant overhead to any get request made to the server.

So is there a quick and easy way to hide the hidden score from the user while still making the pagination work?

Comment: Why does your nextPage need the hidden score at all? Limit and offset only require the number of rows you skip and take https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/queries-limit.html

Comment: because I dont want to use limit and offset. I destroys the performance of my query, since it has to load offset*page_size+limit*page_size rows and needs a perfect index (meaning all filter and sort conditions) to be efficient. If you use to hidden score to page instead it only needs to load a slice of the data. I tested it and my method is 20x faster

Comment: Is hidden score a column (or multiple?) or a calculated value on each query?

Comment: The score is stored in a column per offer and gets regulararly recalculated based on factors like repution, price, posting date etc. when any of these factors change

Comment: Why would applying indexing to a single column become a problem? Does the update become unacceptably slow? You'll need to give a simplified example (with dummy algo)

Comment: Its a bit complicated, but basically, I also need to apply a filter to the the results which depends on a join on a very large table.  This massively decreases performance the larger the offset gets. I tried optimizing it but I really can't get it fast enough with LIMIT and OFFSET. And from what I've learned online it just seams to more clean approach in general

Comment: If the score won't change between paging, why not just use the row ID itself?

Comment: because adjusting the row id would mean chaning every single row id after it after every single update

Comment: Wrap everything in a view, use the built-in AES support to decrypt the parameter.

Comment: sounds interesting, thanks

Comment: You can always encrypt it.  But I don't see the point.  The attacker can already see the order the rows are returned in and reverse engineer that.  Does the identity of the 8th significant digit really contain useful information to putative attacker?

Comment: I'd say yes since it allows an attacker to determine the exact score of a specific offer. It would at least make testing hypothesis much more easy